# Know if a variable is an instance of a class or a struct

Tags: swift, class, struct

There is a way to know if a variable in swift is an instance of a class or a struct? I'm trying to do a deepCopy but I'm only interested in doing that if it is an instance of a class, not a struct

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this

```
    func getDeepCopy<T>(object: T) -> T {

    if (T.self is AnyClass) {
       // It is an instance of a class
       return deepCopy(object)
    }
    // It is an instance of a struct
    return object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your function like this:

```
func getDeepCopy<T: AnyObject>(object: T) -> T
```